# php soapclient keeps sockets open

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, soap-client

I have a Laravel project running queued tasks to send emails. The queue manager is run by the supervisor so the PHP script is constantly in the memory until it's restarted. For sending emails I use Bronto which communicates through SOAP. They provided a PHP library via composer, I checked their code they use PHP's SoapClient class to send the request. After a certain time (sometimes it's less than 30 minutes) the script starts crashing because I cannot open more TCP socket. I ran netstat on the server and it turned out that a lot of connections/sockets are still open, PHP doesn't close them, that's why a new one cannot be opened. The `keep-alive` flag is false and since the script doesn't terminate I should close those connections somehow. Any ideas would be appreciated.